# Receive 401 error when try to retrieve Office 365 Audit log with MS Graph API with PowerShell

Tags: powershell, microsoft-graph-api, office365api

I am trying to retrieve the audit log to track user license allocation changes. 
This is the URI I use in MS Graph Explorer. It works fine in there, I can get data I want out of it.

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/auditLogs/directoryAudits?$filter=activityDisplayName eq 'Update user'
```

But when I try to query with the same URI through PowerShell with the Authentication Token generated with the exact same Office 365 credential, I got error saying `Invoke-RestMethod : The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized.`

Did I miss anything in terms of getting the Authentication Token?
Here is the GetAuthToken function I use

```
Function GetAuthToken
{
    param
        (
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
        $TenantName
        )
    Import-Module Azure
    $clientId = "ef9bcdf0-a675-4cd5-9ec3-fa549f9ee4cf" 
    $redirectUri      = "https://RedirectURI.com" 
    $resourceAppIdURI = "https://graph.microsoft.com"
    $authority = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/$TenantName"
    $authContext = New-Object "Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.AuthenticationContext" -ArgumentList $authority
    $Credential = Import-Clixml -Path "C:\MIMA\tom_admin_cred.xml"
    $AADCredential = New-Object "Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.UserCredential" -ArgumentList $credential.UserName,$credential.Password
    $authResult = $authContext.AcquireToken($resourceAppIdURI, $clientId,$AADCredential)
    return $authResult
}
```

And this is the code I use to retrieve the report

```
$token = GetAuthToken -TenantName $tenant  
$authHeader = @{
    'Content-Type'='application\json'
    'Authorization'=$token.CreateAuthorizationHeader()
    }
$uri = "https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/auditLogs/directoryAudits?$filter=activityDisplayName eq 'Update user'"
$auditReports = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $uri –Headers $authHeader –Method Get
```

Answer (score 1):

Problem fixed! The issue was caused by Azure AD App was not granted "Auditlog.Read.All" permission. "Modify permission" in the MSGraph Explorer somehow does not apply to the actual Azure AD permission settings (Or it's using a different built-in Azure AD app?).

So I have to sign in to Azure portal -> Azure AD -> App registration -> Settings and added the permissions under Required Permissions. Please note, the change does take a while to take effect. I simply waited overnight and next morning I was able to retrieve the report without 401 error.

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following code:

```
    $token = GetAuthToken -TenantName $tenant  
    $authHeader = @{
        'Content-Type'='application\json'
        'Authorization'=$token.CreateAuthorizationHeader()
        }
    $uri = "https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/auditLogs/directoryAudits?$filter=activityDisplayName eq 'Update user'"

   try{
        $auditReports = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $uri –Headers $authHeader –Method Get
   }
   catch{
        $auditReports = $_.Exception.Response
   }
```

Comment: The error I am getting with catch is still "Unauthorized"